# Swift: Gui is not updated / much too late

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I am currently programming a Quiz-App for iphone using swift and xcode. Since a week I a stuck with a problem, i wasn't able so solve up to today.

**Little Background Information:**

All Questions are stored online on a server and are downloaded just in time. The Questions always contain images, so it takes some time to load them. This is why I am pre-loading the next question in background while the user is still thinking about the current question. Therefore I use the class *QuestionLoader* which extends *Thread*.

**The Problem Situation:**

When the user answers a question and presses the *continue*-button, the function *goToNextQuestion()* is triggered which shows the next question to the user. Either the pre-loading of the next question is finished and it can be shown instantly or the next question is still loading and we have to wait.

**The Problem:**

Now if we have to wait, I want to show a Loading-Label and -Indicator. Both are in the gui (placed with interface-builder) and hidden at the time. I do it like this:

```
func goToNextQuestion()
{
    //check if next question is already ready
    if (nextQuestionLoader.isFinished==false)
    {
        //not ready, so wait and show waiting indication
        labelLoading.isHidden = false
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating()
        while(nextQuestionLoader.isFinished == false) {}
        //question i now ready, hide waiting indication
        labelLoading.isHidden = true
        loadingIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }

    //so next question is ready and all good
}
```

What I want to happen is that when the user pressed *continue* and the next question is not ready yet, that the *loadingIndicator* and the *labelLoading* are shown until the question is ready.

Now what happens is that *continue* is pressed the there is nothing shown and the gui is blocked util the question is ready, then it shows the next question and the same thing happens with the following question.

[Screenshots of the area of my gui that is concerned for better visualitzation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7l6Wy.jpg)
(Sorry for the different number of points gained in the screenshots, does not have to do with the problem, simply 2 different screenshots)

**So the gui update does not happen before the question is loaded completely and does not happen immediately as it should!**

**Additional Information**

- I tried the showing of the loading indicators at other points of the code and they show correctly, so there is no problem with this.
- When i put *print*-command before and after the while-loop and follow the output in the terminal, I see that the print-commands are correctly executed before and after the while-loop. But the gui-update does only happen afterwards
- The function *goToNextQuestion* is completely executed in the main-thread!

So how can i achieve that the loading-indication is shown directly and *after* it is shown, the while-loop waits for the finish of the other thread?

I am really desperate because i have no idea at all how to solve this.

I would really really appreciate some help from you!

Thank you very much in advance for your time!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your approach.

First, you should not use `NSThread`/`Thread`. The system class `URLSession` handles async downloading for you. (And creating threads is expensive and error-prone.) Use `URLSession` instead. You should be able to find lots of examples online, including here.

Second, you can't block the main thread like you're doing with your

```
    while(nextQuestionLoader.isFinished == false) {}
```

Code. Since your download is running on a background thread it will keep running, but by blocking the main thread everything will freeze until the download completes. Your UI changes don't get a chance to be drawn on the screen until the download is complete.

What you should do is use `URLSession` using either a delegate method or a completion closure. It supports both approaches.

I have a project called [Async_demo](https://github.com/DuncanMC/Async_demo/tree/master/Async_demo) on Github that includes working code that shows how to use `URLSession`. It's a simplified example, but it should get you started.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will try.